# Flutter Textbox decoration combining OutlineInputBorder and UnderlineInputBorder

Tags: flutter

How can I achieve below textFormfield border decoration in flutter. I tried using OutlineInputBorder and UnderlineInputBorder but could not get it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example with `enabledBorder` and `focusedBorder` property to set `OutlineInputBorder` and `UnderlineInputBorder` (I usually use this).

```
TextField(
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: Color(0xFF565FDF),
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //counterText: "",
        labelText: "Text hint",
        filled: true,
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF565FDF))
        ),
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF565FDF)),
        focusColor: const Color(0xFF565FDF)
      ),
    );
```

Set the border as you need.

Comment: I don't think it will give the desired output. on focus the UnderlineInputBorder will be replaced with the OutlineInputBorder, but won't be visible at the same time as shown in the image. I managed to implement it by wrapping the textformfiled with Containers and playing with BoxDecoration borders

Comment: If you still can't solve your problem yet, please share your code and I can try to solve it.